# In what order should the Appleseed movies be watched?

Tags: appleseed

In what order should the *Appleseed* movies be watched?

- *Appleseed*
- *Appleseed Ex Machina*
- *Appleseed Alpha*
- *Appleseed XIII: Tartaros*
- *Appleseed XIII: Ouranos*
- other else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Watching the movies in the order they were released is a good idea. Referencing [Appleseed FAQ](https://appleseed.fandom.com/wiki/Frequently_Asked_Questions#What_timeframe_is_the_series_set_in?):

1. [The Appleseed OVA from 1988](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appleseed_(1988_film)).
2. The 2004 movie is set in 2131.
3. The 2007 movie is set in 2138.
4. Appleseed XIII the OVA (13 episodes) from 2011-2012.

Also, note that *Appleseed Alpha* is a standalone from the others.

Answer (score 2):

To contrast with the other answer, here's a roughly chronological order (of just the movies).

1. [Appleseed Alpha](http://myanimelist.net/anime/22677/Appleseed_Alpha)
2. [Appleseed (2004)](http://myanimelist.net/anime/54/Appleseed_(Movie))
3. [Appleseed Ex Machina](http://myanimelist.net/anime/2969/Appleseed_Saga_Ex_Machina)

Also, note that there is a movie adaptation of *Appleseed XIII* if you are interested. However, according to [the Appleseed Wiki](http://appleseed.wikia.com/wiki/Appleseed_XIII), it's actually a "relaunch of the series following the 2003 and 2007 films."